# Align equivalent observation in R

Tags: r, excel

I am relatively new with R. I looked for a reply on the forum, unsuccessfully
I need to align values coming from 2 different columns.
For example, I have:

`Educ    wage
 a       e
 a       j
 e       a
 j       a`

and I need:

`Educ    Wage
  a       a
  a       a
  j       j
  e       e`

Knowing that I have to do this on a large dataset and that **I have a different number of values in column "Educ" and in Column "Wage".**

I want to thanks the Stackoverflow community and again I am very sorry if my question has already been asked.

Comment: check this one out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right

Comment: Your problem is not sufficiently defined. If both columns really contain exactly the same values as in your example you can just copy one column to have it twice.

Comment: @ygaft I already looked at this post. The problem is that this works for multiple dataset but I am working on a single dataset.

Comment: @Roland , I need a code to automatically align values which are the same in two different columns. Or you might know a trick on excel. I think my problem is very trivial.

Comment: Following @Roland's point, what would you want to happen when the columns have different data, e.g. `data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 1), y = c(3, 1, 2))`?

Comment: I suspect you want to `merge` two data.frames. Difficult to say without a representative example.

Comment: @MikkoMarttila I want to to put a NA if the x column does not match the y column.

Comment: @Roland I am working on a single dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your columns contain **exactly** the same data but in different order than this would work:

```
df <- data.frame(Educ = c("a","a","e","j"), Wage = c("e","j","a","a"), stringsAsFactors = F )
df$Educ <- sort(df$Educ)
df$Wage <- sort(df$Wage)
```

EDIT: If the values are not the same and column length differ than I can think of this data.table solution:

```
require(data.table)

dt.left <- data.table(x = c("a","z","a","b","c","d","b","c"))
dt.rght <- data.table(x = c("a","e","c","b","f"))

dt.left[ , dum := paste0(x,1:.N), by = "x"]
dt.rght[ , dum := paste0(x,1:.N), by = "x"]

merge(dt.left,dt.rght,by = "dum", all = T)
```

You can play with the `all` var e.g `all.x` , `all.y`. Since it uses data.table you will also be very fast on big data sets.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I just edited my post: my number of observation in the 2 columns are different.

Comment: Hey @J.Perez. Since columns in a data frame are always of the same length do you have vectors instead? Or do your columns contain NA's ?

Comment: I want to be able to put NAs if the left column does not match the right column. At the moment, I just have two columns of 2 different length which contain NA.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your question, try to adapt this code:

```
df_ord<-data.frame(cbind(Educ=as.character(df[order(df$Educ),"Educ"]),Wage=as.character(df[order(df$Wage),"Wage"])))
df_ord
  Educ Wage
1    a    a
2    a    a
3    e    e
4    j    j
```

Input data:

```
df<-data.frame(Educ=c("a","a","e","j"),Wage=c("e","j","a","a"))
> df
  Educ Wage
1    a    e
2    a    j
3    e    a
4    j    a
```

**WARNING: This approach works only if you have same elements in value and numbers in both columns.**

Comment: thanks for your reply. I just edited my post: my number of observation in the 2 columns are different.

Comment: Ok, but what you want as desired output? Please provide an example with differents values in 2 columns